# Puppet use master's ssh key for git clone?

Tags: ssh, puppet, rsa

I'm using the [vcsrepo](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/vcsrepo/1.0.2) puppet module to sync git repositories.

```
  # install git repo
  vcsrepo { "/home/repo":
    ensure   => present,
    provider => git,
    source   => "git@bitbucket.org:pk2klic/test.git",
  }
```

It's working on the master server where I've made an RSA key and uploaded the public key to bitbucket.

I have many agent nodes so it would be impractical to manually upload keys for each node.

Is there a workaround for this where I can use the master's ssh key to clone when applying my puppet file? Or am I better off trying to create an automated process for creating new keys on every node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you need to be creating new keys for each node. That's the whole point of key-based SSH authentication.

If a single server is compromised, you can just stop trusting that specific key, replace it, and move on.

Now, if you *really* wanted to do it the way you're suggesting, with a single key, then you will need to make sure that the private key is on each host. I'll leave this as an exercise for you to figure out how to do this.

Then you would configure `~/.ssh/config` to specify the key you want to use when accessing that repository. You might want to do something like:

Your puppet config:

```
  # install git repo
  vcsrepo { "/home/repo":
    ensure   => present,
    provider => git,
    source   => "git@bitbucket:pk2klic/test.git",
  }
```

And `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host            bitbucket
    Hostname        bitbucket.org
    IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/id_rsa-bitbucket
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Note the change I've made to the git repo here. I'm using the alias `bitbucket` instead of the real hostname. The real hostname is set in the `.ssh/config` file. I'm assuming that you've put your shared private key in `~/.ssh/id_rsa-bitbucket`

This way if the user just pushes/pulls in that repo, it will use the specific key, but if they want to clone their own personal stuff from BitBucket they can just use the real `git@bitbucket.org:example/example.git`, and it will just use their personal SSH key (as it would normally).